# divide NSTimeInterval to 24 hours

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have 2 NSDate, and i want to divide it into 24 hours, i need to know how many minutes in each hour. and then save the data into an array.

Sorry for my english.
i draw a pic to describe my problem.
Thanks!
[image: update]

Comment: Usually, there are 60 minutes per hour :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to determine the number of minutes between two dates and divide this interval by 24. The below code should illustrate a method for obtaining the time interval between your dates:

```
NSDate *startDate = [NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:@"2012-12-01"];
NSDate *endDate = [NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:@"2012-12-02"];

unsigned int unitFlags = NSMinuteCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:unitFlags fromDate:startDate  toDate:endDate  options:0];

NSLog(@"Number of minutes: %lu\n", [comps minute]);
```

Take the number of minutes from this calculation and divide by 24, to determine the number of minutes in each range.

Comment: maybe i didn't describe it right, i didn't mean evenly divide, i want to develop a chart , to show user how many minute they spend in each hour. when user run my app, i get a startDate, when they quit , i get a endDate, i have to get an array(as the picture shows) , so i can add the minutes in each hour to the database.

Comment: How are you determining how much time is spent in your app? Or ... is that the question?

Comment: right now i,m using applicationDidBecomeActive to get a startDate, and  applicationWillResignActive to get a endDate , is this right?

Answer (score 0):

Well, NSDate objects are not very useful on their own, what you are looking for is NSDateComponents.  Here is a short sample of how to extract them from an NSDate object:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:date];
NSInteger hour = [dateComponents hour]; //etc
```

First you can determine which date comes first by using the method `earlierDate:` ( `NSDate *firstDate = [date1 earlierDate:date2'` ) and the extract the relevant info from them as shown above.  You will have the days of both as well as the start/end hours and minutes.  I'm sure you can work out how many minutes fall into each hour.  It will be 60 for all but the first and last unless they both are exactly 0 minutes.  The first hour will be (60 - x) minutes and the last hour will be x minutes (x being the minute value from above).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming date2 and date1 are NSDate*

NSTimeInterval timeDifference = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];

Divide timeDifference by 60.0 to get minutes.